# Grouping variables and adding them to the end of the table

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like the following:

| Type | Number |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| E | 3 |
| C | 4 |
| D | 5 |
| C | 6 |
| G | 7 |

I would like to make a table where I group Types (A-C) and add these same observations to the bottom of the table. So the new table would look like:

| Type | Number |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| E | 3 |
| C | 4 |
| D | 5 |
| C | 6 |
| G | 7 |
| A-C | 1 |
| A-C | 2 |
| E | 3 |
| A-C | 4 |
| D | 5 |
| A-C | 6 |
| G | 7 |

Is this possible? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to work out your groupings then bind the two dataframes together, e.g.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "Type   Number
A   1
B   2
E   3
C   4
D   5
C   6
G   7", header = TRUE)

tmp <- df %>%
  mutate(Type = ifelse(Type %in% c("A", "B", "C"),
                       "A-C", Type))
result <- bind_rows(df, tmp)
result
#>    Type Number
#> 1     A      1
#> 2     B      2
#> 3     E      3
#> 4     C      4
#> 5     D      5
#> 6     C      6
#> 7     G      7
#> 8   A-C      1
#> 9   A-C      2
#> 10    E      3
#> 11  A-C      4
#> 12    D      5
#> 13  A-C      6
#> 14    G      7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Same approach but with base R (i.e. don't need the dplyr package):

```r
df <- read.table(text = "Type   Number
A   1
B   2
E   3
C   4
D   5
C   6
G   7", header = TRUE)

tmp <- df
tmp$Type <- ifelse(df$Type %in% c("A", "B", "C"), "A-C", df$Type)
rbind(df, tmp)
#>    Type Number
#> 1     A      1
#> 2     B      2
#> 3     E      3
#> 4     C      4
#> 5     D      5
#> 6     C      6
#> 7     G      7
#> 8   A-C      1
#> 9   A-C      2
#> 10    E      3
#> 11  A-C      4
#> 12    D      5
#> 13  A-C      6
#> 14    G      7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Or transform, to avoid tmp dataframe: `rbind(df, transform(df, Type = ifelse(Type %in% c("A", "B", "C"), "A-C", Type)))`

Answer (score 1):

Using *forcats* factor collapse:

```
library(forcats)

rbind(df, transform(df, Type = fct_collapse(Type, `A-C` = c("A", "B", "C"))))
#    Type Number
# 1     A      1
# 2     B      2
# 3     E      3
# 4     C      4
# 5     D      5
# 6     C      6
# 7     G      7
# 8   A-C      1
# 9   A-C      2
# 10    E      3
# 11  A-C      4
# 12    D      5
# 13  A-C      6
# 14    G      7
```

Comment: Using a purpose-designed function is often the best approach - less chance of a 'gotcha' / unforeseen error - great answer (+1)